# How to use C# struct array initialization in C/C++ code?

Tags: c#, c++, c, struct

Say, I have the following struct in `C#`:

```
public struct MyStructCSharp
{
    private byte[] offsets = new byte[] { 28, 20, 27, 36 };
}
```

How do you do the same in `C/C++`?

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
typedef struct _MyStructCpp
{
    _MyStructCpp()
    {
        offsets[] = {28, 20, 27, 36};
    }

private:
    unsigned char offsets[];
}MyStructCpp;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I initialize normal array member variable in initializer list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517277/how-can-i-initialize-normal-array-member-variable-in-initializer-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign to an array after it has been declared.  Aside from that, the syntax would be wrong.  If it only ever has 4 elements then do this or just use a `vector` if you can.

```
struct MyStruct {

  MyStruct() {
    offsets[0] = 28;
    offsets[1] = 20;
    offsets[2] = 27;
    offsets[3] = 36;
  }

private:
  unsigned char offsets[4];
};
```

Also, do not begin your type names with an underscore.  These are reserved and it could lead to nastiness.

Comment: What if I have a 1000 numbers in the offsets definition. Does it mean I have to re-type them all? Is there an easier way?

Comment: @ahmd0 : The easier way is to use `std::array<>` or `boost::array<>` instead of a C-array. There are many answers on SO demonstrating how this approach works.

Comment: @ahmd0: Well I answered as best I could given the information you presented.  You *should* be using collection types (`vector<T>`, some of the new C++11 collections, etc) whenever and wherever you can.  If you don't know up front how large the array is then you have two choices; use a `vector` (better) or declare `offsets` as `unsigned char*` and allocate it dynamically in your constructor as Mr. Tamer showed you in his answer.  Make sure to define a destructor which deallocates the memory though.  Honestly, just use a `vector`.

Comment: @EdS. : Destructor, copy constructor, copy assignment operator, move constructor, _and_ move assignment operator. Honestly, `new` is no good here.

Comment: @ildjarn: Yeah, it's really not.  OP, read and understand; [The rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Comment: @ildjarn: I totally agree. All I need is to init a const memory array of bytes of larger but fixed size. Doing all that dynamic array stuff is a complete overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a fixed number of values, Ed S's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9916924/368167) is the appropriate way.

Else, You can't do the same, because you can only initialize a variable member in the initializer list, and such assignment cannot be made in the initializer list.

However, the C# version is possible thanks to using `new`, so maybe it is a good solution to do the same in C++, however, you will have to have the length of `offsets` and assign each value individually:

```
typedef struct _MyStructCpp
{
    _MyStructCpp(int size)
    {
        _size = size; // Say 4
        offsets = new unsigned char[size];
        offsets[0] = 28;
        // etc....
    }
private:
    int _size;
    unsigned char* offsets;
}MyStructCpp;
```

However, you should keep in mind that you have just allocated a dynamic memory, so you should clear it in the destructor.

Comment: "*However, the C# version is possible thanks to using `new`, so maybe it is a good solution to do the same in C++*" I would argue that encouraging `new` in C++ is never a good thing.

Comment: @ildjarn: I agree with you that it's not a good thing when the size of the array is known at compile time, if not, it's the only way I know.

Comment: If not, that's why there's `std::vector<>`. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn: As far as I know, `std::vector<>` use `new`, so are you talking about performance or about easiness?

Comment: I'm talking about object lifetime and avoiding memory leaks. `new` would require that the class have a non-trivial copy constructor, copy assignment operator, move constructor, and move assignment operator in order to manage lifetime correctly; `std::vector<>` would require nothing special at all. (And technically, `std::vector<>` doesn't use `new`, it uses (by default) `std::allocator<>::allocate` and `std::allocator<>::construct`.)

Comment: Initializing array that is not set as static or const will result in all those bytes written into it at every iteration the code is called. So it's terrible inefficient (in C++ speeds.) Quite OK for C# though...

Comment: Whether or not `vector` uses `new` is irrelevant.  `new` must be called to allocate memory dynamically.  `vector` knows how to do this correctly, which cannot be said for every custom type that a given C++ programmer will create.  "Don't ever use new" is overly dogmatic.  Really, use `new` only when you absolutely need to and you know what you are doing.  This is rare in 'modern' C++.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you have the support:

```
struct MyStructCpp
{
    private:
    unsigned char offsets[4]{28, 20, 27, 36};
};
```

Well, since you don't have the support:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct()
    {
        unsigned char temp[] = {28, 20, 27, 36};
        std::copy(temp, temp + MAX, offsets);
    }
    private:
    static const std::size_t MAX = 4;
    unsigned char offsets[MAX];
};
```

(However, as mentioned `std::vector` would be better. Just showing the way if I was constrained to using a plain-old array.)

Comment: What kind of "support" is needed for this?

Comment: @merlin2011: In C++11 you can initialize a member array using the list initializer syntax.  You previously could not.

Comment: @merlin2011 : Specifically, the subsets of C++11 proposed in [N2756](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm) and [N2672](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2672.htm).

Comment: Here's what I get from VS2010. error C2473: 'offsets' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list.
error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Comment: @ahmd0 : VC++ 2010 supports neither uniform initialization nor non-static data member initializers. This answer currently only works on bleeding-edge compilers.

Comment: Well, I need it for a "dull-edge compiler"

Comment: @ahmd0: I added a different version since you don't have the support.

Comment: Ugh, just use a collection type.

Comment: @ahmd0 : That's why you should mention what compiler you're using in your question. ;-]

Comment: @EdS.: Of course, but is saying `use X instead` an adequate answer?

Comment: @Jesse: In this case, yes.  You have a beginner who is delving into the large and complex world that is C++.  They should learn how to do things the "right" way as soon as possible. I don't think anything in his problem description requires the use of maintaining a pointer member or a raw array.

Answer (score 0):

For a *fixed* size array, use `std::array<>`:

```
struct MyStructCpp
{
    MyStructCpp()
      : offsets(initOffsets())
    { }

private:
    std::array<unsigned char, 4> offsets;

    static std::array<unsigned char, 4> initOffsets()
    {
        std::array<unsigned char, 4> ret = {{28, 20, 27, 36}};
        return ret;
    }
};
```

All non-ancient compilers will elide the apparent copy here via NRVO. For standard library implementations lacking `std::array<>`, use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Array](http://www.boost.org/libs/array/) instead.

For a *dynamically* sized array, use `std::vector<>`. Do not use `new`, except as a last resort.

(Also, unrelated, but don't use the `typedef struct` idiom – that's a C idiom that is pointless and noisy in C++.)

Answer (score -3):

```
char offsets[4]={28,20,27,36};
```